IntelliJ IDE Internal Errors with Kotlin plugin
Perhaps someone has an idea about the following problems (see below) and has some workaround. If you know about a workaround or an update regarding the following problem, please let me know.
I have installed the latest version of IntelliJ on the 2024-11-13 and I am getting the following errors:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Check failed.
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.analysis.api.impl.base.lifetime.KaBaseLifetimeTracker.afterLeavingAnalysis(KaBaseLifetimeTracker.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.analysis.api.impl.base.sessions.KaBaseSessionProvider.afterLeavingAnalysis(KaBaseSessionProvider.kt:71)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.analysis.api.impl.base.sessions.KaBaseSessionProvider.afterLeavingAnalysis(KaBaseSessionProvider.kt:62)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.debugger.core.KotlinSourcePositionProvider.computeSourcePosition(KotlinSourcePositionProvider.kt:216)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.debugger.core.KotlinSourcePositionProvider.computeSourcePosition(KotlinSourcePositionProvider.kt:49)


This is the IntelliJ version I am using:
Build #IU-242.23726.103, built on October 23, 2024
This is a screenshot of the error message:

My project is a Gradle project using build.gradle.kts with the following libraries:
plugins {

    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building a CLI application in Java.
    application

    val springBootVersion = "3.3.5"
    id("org.springframework.boot") version springBootVersion // Replace with the latest version
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.6" // Replace with the latest version
    val kotlinSpringPluginVersion = "2.0.21"
    kotlin("jvm") version kotlinSpringPluginVersion // Use the appropriate Kotlin version
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version kotlinSpringPluginVersion // Adds support for Spring in Kotlin

    id("com.ncorti.ktfmt.gradle") version "0.21.0"
}

repositories {
    // Use Maven Central for resolving dependencies.
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {

    implementation("org.bkwsu.registration:events-web-model:2.0-SNAPSHOT")

    implementation("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.7.4")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")

    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server")
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.nimbusds/nimbus-jose-jwt
    // implementation("com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:9.46")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")

    // Use the Kotlin JUnit 5 integration.
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit5")

    // Use the JUnit 5 integration.
    testImplementation(libs.junit.jupiter.engine)

    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher")

    // Optional dependencies for testing
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.assertj/assertj-core
    testImplementation("org.assertj:assertj-core:3.26.3")
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core
    testImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-core:5.14.2")
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito.kotlin/mockito-kotlin
    testImplementation("org.mockito.kotlin:mockito-kotlin:5.4.0")


    // This dependency is used by the application.
    implementation(libs.guava)

}


I get IDE errors quite frequently too, so I'm following your question to see if you get any answers. Did you click the button to send a report of the errors to Jetbrains? By the way, today, 2024.3 has been released, so you're no longer running the latest. However, I've just experienced an error even with this latest version. By the way, I get these errors both with my company's large project as well as my trivial personal playground/helloworld project.

@k314159 Good lord, you are right, let me update my version to see if there are any improvements.

After upgrading this error went away.

I am not sure why my previous answer was hidden.
There is a possibility to report the issue in this window.
Please send me an ID of the reported issue.
If you are unable to do it, then please create a ticket via YouTrack:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue
Thank you!

I believe it was deleted by moderators because this site is not a customer support site. Answers should be worded in a way that will help all future readers - think of it as like a Knowledge Base.

I have done so multiple times before. However this error disappeared after I have upgraded to Build #IU-243.21565.193, built on November 13, 2024.
I still get lots of highlighting errors in Kotlin after working on the project for some time. These errors go away when I recreate the project which I have to do multiple times a day.
